# Highcharts Area graph, use 2 fill colors above / below X axis

Tags: colors, highcharts

In `Highcharts`, I'd like to fill an Area graph with 2 colors, positive values get one color, negative values get another color.  I've been able to do this with a `linearGradient`, but this must be adjusted based upon the `size of the container`.

Is there a more general way of doing this, e.g. setting values > `0 color 1, values < 0 color 2?`

See my JSFiddle for more information and an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GNvur/2/

Comment: I think your solution with linearGradient is more relevant to this problem. their is no need to create dummy series. I'd like to read highcharts officials comment on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The parameter we were looking for is named  `negativeColor`. Use it in an area serie like  this :

```
   series: [{
        type:'area',
        data:chartValues,
        color: "#FF0000",
        threshold: 0,
        negativeColor: '#00FFFF',

        marker : {
            enabled: true
        }
    }]
```

see the result in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNvur/24/).

Comment: Very much so the best answer, the only problem I find now is that when the line goes below 0 it will start acting strange (a value is added each second like in the example on the website: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I posted a question on the above issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833912/graph-sliding-strangely-with-negativecolor-activated