# Graph sliding strangely with negativeColor activated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to show some real time changing data in a moving chart (adding a point each second) much like the [updating spline example on the highcharts website](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update). To have a clear view of (the difference between) the positive and negative portions of the line I chose to use the `negativeColor` attribute of the serie.

This actually does exactly what I want except for the fact that the parts that are situated below 0 will move really strangely(almost like the line is drunk). I have changed the jsFiddle of the example to reflect my problem: [edited example](http://jsfiddle.net/8QdG5/).

My question is: How can I make the 'below 0' part of the line move like the 'above 0' part?

Any help or insight into this problem is welcome.

Comment: yeah this is a strange behavour, we can see what's happening a little bit by using a chart type: 'line' instead of spline. But I think its a bug from highchart, you may need to post an issue with this example on : https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues?state=open

Comment: I just posted an issue, thanks for the response!

Comment: Just for future info, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1899)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in the next version of [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts) (current version is 3.0.2 so I'd guess that would be 3.1 or 3.0.3). See the [issue on Github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1899) for more information.